# Upnp -implementing in c#

Tags: c#

i am creating a discovery module ith upnp
i am developing on xp with the upnp.dll - i saw that the interop dont expose the devicefindercallback - how can i implement it to use upnp as async

i saw that in win7 it is exposed

Comment: Well, my mistake to post a good answer to a sloppy question.  I'll save it for a more appreciative questioner.  Bye.